# Run PHP in Linux server

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

How to run PHP file on startup?

PHP File Used Socket. 
In `While(true) {}` and `set_time_limit (0)`

How to run this in startup Linux ( Ubuntu ) in Background ;

Used :

`nohup php <file> &`

&&

```
php <file> -q &
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should kept in the root folder of your linux as it would automatically run

Comment: That's why put a index.php file in the root folder where the default index file is present